# Why spurious pulses are likely in partial discharges?

Tags: particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, quantization, ionization-energy

My notes

> The gas multiplication in the proportional counters is based on the
>   secondary ionization created in collisions between electrons and
>   neutral gas molecules, resulting in some visible or ultraviolet
>   photons.  Those photons are undesirable below the Geiger-Mueller
>   region because they can lead to spurious pulses, \cite{knoll}, here $\Delta A > 0$.

I am also interested in how you can minimize such pulses in partial discharges.

Why spurious pulses are more likely in partial discharges than complete discharges? 
Complete discharge corresponds to the Geiger-Mueller region.